# SQL Groupe int by groupe and by date

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a mysql database and I want  to make a SQL request but i don't sucess this. I want this :

```
    date   | groupe1 | groupe2 | groupe3 | TOTAL
2018-02-15 | 1.3     |  4      |  0      | 5.3
2018-02-14 |  0      | 6.1     |  0      | 6.1
2018-02-13 | 0       | 5.4     | 4.9     | 10.3
```

But with my request I have this :

```
    date   | groupe1 | groupe2 | groupe3 | TOTAL
2018-02-15 |  0      |  4      |  0      | 4.0
2018-02-15 | 1.3     |  0      |  0      | 1.3
2018-02-14 |  0      | 6.1     |  0      | 6.1
2018-02-13 | 0       | 5.4     |  0      | 5.4
2018-02-13 | 0       | 0       | 3.9     | 3.9
2018-02-13 | 0       | 0       | 1       | 1
```

This is my request :

```
SELECT date, groupe1, groupe2, groupe3, ROUND(groupe1 + groupe2+ groupe3, 1 ) AS TOTAL
FROM lesGroupes
WHERE journal LIKE journal1 OR 
      journal LIKE  journal2
```

So I want to transpose the data to display a single number by groupe and by date

Thank you for avance,
Good evening.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Fix your schema

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
SELECT date, 
    SUM(groupe1), 
    SUM(groupe2), 
    SUM(groupe3), 
    SUM(ROUND(groupe1 + groupe2+ groupe3, 1))
FROM yourTable
WHERE journal LIKE journal1 OR journal LIKE journal2
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: It's perfect ! Thank you so much ! :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to [aggregate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) your data grouping by the date

```
SELECT date, SUM(groupe1), SUM(groupe2), SUM(groupe3) ,SUM(groupe1+groupe2+groupe3)
FROM lesGroupes
WHERE journal LIKE 'journal1' OR journal LIKE 'journal2' 
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want ! Thank you so much ! :P

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty straightforward sum and group:

```
SELECT `date`, SUM(groupe1), SUM(groupe2), SUM(groupe3), SUM(groupe1+groupe2+groupe3)
FROM yourTable
WHERE journal IN ('journal1', 'journal2')
GROUP BY `date`
```

Note: `date` is a reserved word, you should avoid using it as a column name or it can cause you headaches.  You can also simplify your `LIKE..etc` to `IN()` (and you should use `=` instead of `LIKE` unless you need to search for partial strings.)

Comment: It's perfect ! Thank you so much for your response and your advice I take note! :D